# retrieve from entity manager before ID is given

Tags: php, symfony, persist, entitymanager

Here is the situation -

I need to persist an object between pages.  On the first page I create the object, and create a form for it.  On the second page, I persist the object.  The user then has an option to go back and edit their choices, or finish and post.

I would prefer not to flush my changes to the database until the user is done editing the object.  The problem is that the object doesn't get a unique ID until it is flushed to the database.

Does anyone know how I can retrieve the persisted yet unflushed object?  Is this even possible?  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You serialize the object until you complete all it's properties. You can hold the serialized object in the session to persist between pages. When you are ready to update or insert just unserialize it and put it into the database.

EDIT: example

```
// page 1
$object->setProperty($value);
$_SESSION['object'] = serialize($object);

// page 2
$object = unserialize($_SESSION['object']);
// use $object

$_SESSION['object'] = serialize($object);


// page N
$object = unserialize($_SESSION['object']);
$object->insertIntoDB();
```

EDIT 2 - Don't forget to include the class definition in all pages that unserialize the object or else it won't work.

Comment: sweet.  I tried using the session earlier, but I was missing the part on serialization.  I'll try it out, thanks for the advice.  If it works I'll  consider this my answer.

Comment: mmm.. the object doesn't seem to be serializable via the php function.  maybe theres a symfony function I'm missing... there error is Item "couponname" for "O:33:"Frontend\UserBundle\Entity\Coupon":20:{s:5:".... thats just from calling \serialize($coupon);
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime

Comment: k i think i got it, using 

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;

and

 $serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new 
                JsonEncoder()));
                $json = $serializer->serialize($coupon, 'json');

Comment: but now i cant find any way to unserialize it back into a coupon object ^^

Comment: $coupon = $serializer->decode($json, 'json'); gives me an array instead of a coupon object

Comment: man... so it looks like i would have to write a script to unparse all that json... is this really the best way to use persist an entity between pages without saving it to the database?

Comment: well, i don't know if encoding in json will make it possible to get back your object. the unserialize php function will create an instance of the type of object you had. with decode, you'll get an array or a stdClass object.

Comment: what was the errors when serializing? do you have any references to other objects ?